# Changing the language of the formatted_address called by google Places API autocomplete method

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

The data that i have received using google Places API is giving me formatted_address field in my local language. I want it to be in English.

I have enabled google Places Api and used autocomplete method to load suggestions. A simple html page to load the received data is created. I have tried setting the language option to "en" in script tag.

HTML:

```
<div id="info-table">
  Name: <span id="place_name"></span><br>
  Place id: <span id="place_id"></span><br>
  Address :<span id="place_address"></span><br>
  Phone : <span id="phone_no"></span><br>
  Openhours: <span id="open_time"></span><br>
  Open Now : <span id="open_now"></span><br>
  website : <span id="website"></span><br>
  photo :<br> <img id="photo" src="" style="display:none;" />
</div>

<div>
<p>
<span id="all-data"></span>
</p>
</div>


<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap&language=en&region=US">
</script>
```

JS:

```
function initMap() {

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

  var options = {
  language:'en',
    types: ['establishment']
  };

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

  autocomplete.setFields(['place_id', 'geometry', 'name', 'formatted_address', 'formatted_phone_number', 'opening_hours', 'website', 'photos']);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', placechange);

  function placechange() {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var photos = place.photos;

    $('#all-data').text(JSON.stringify(place));
    $('#place_name').text(place.name);
    $('#place_id').text(place.place_id);
        $('#place_address').text(place.formatted_address);
    $('#phone_no').text(place.formatted_phone_number);
    $('#open_time').text(place.opening_hours.weekday_text[0]);
    $('#open_now').text(place.opening_hours.open_now);
    $('#photo').attr("src",photos[0].getUrl());
    $('#photo').attr("style","width:50%;");
    $('#website').text(place.website);

   }
}
```

Current formatted_address:2nd Floor, 320 ටී බී ජයා මාවත, කොළඹ 01000
Expected formatted_address: 2nd Floor , 320 ,T.B.Jaya Avenue,Colombo 01000.

The current response I'm getting:

```
{"formatted_address":"2nd Floor, 320 ටී බී ජයා මාවත, කොළඹ 01000, Sri Lanka","formatted_phone_number":"0112 683 751","geometry":{"location":{"lat":6.923615999999999,"lng":79.86028599999997},"viewport":{"south":6.922419719708497,"west":79.8594205697085,"north":6.925117680291502,"east":79.86211853029158}},"name":"hSenid Mobile Solutions","opening_hours":{"open_now":true,"periods":[{"close":{"day":1,"time":"1730","hours":17,"minutes":30},"open":{"day":1,"time":"0830","hours":8,"minutes":30}},{"close":{"day":2,"time":"1730","hours":17,"minutes":30},"open":{"day":2,"time":"0830","hours":8,"minutes":30}},{"close":{"day":3,"time":"1730","hours":17,"minutes":30},"open":{"day":3,"time":"0830","hours":8,"minutes":30}},{"close":{"day":4,"time":"1730","hours":17,"minutes":30},"open":{"day":4,"time":"0830","hours":8,"minutes":30}},{"close":{"day":5,"time":"1730","hours":17,"minutes":30},"open":{"day":5,"time":"0830","hours":8,"minutes":30}}],"weekday_text":["Monday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM","Tuesday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM","Wednesday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM","Thursday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM","Friday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM","Saturday: Closed","Sunday: Closed"]},"photos":[{"height":2176,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100291523214478364695/photos\">Malinda Prasad</a>"],"width":4608},{"height":4032,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105380056766383259301/photos\">Sasindu Jayashma</a>"],"width":2268},{"height":2184,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116851599999613156839/photos\">Dinesha Karunathilake</a>"],"width":4608},{"height":2448,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100485539031416489634/photos\">Milinda Arambawela</a>"],"width":3264},{"height":4032,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105380056766383259301/photos\">Sasindu Jayashma</a>"],"width":3024},{"height":960,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114606659795691325467/photos\">hSenid Mobile Solutions</a>"],"width":960},{"height":4032,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105380056766383259301/photos\">Sasindu Jayashma</a>"],"width":2268},{"height":300,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114606659795691325467/photos\">hSenid Mobile Solutions</a>"],"width":300},{"height":720,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114606659795691325467/photos\">hSenid Mobile Solutions</a>"],"width":960}],"place_id":"ChIJO814yhNZ4joRzunigaOMo6A","website":"https://www.hsenidmobile.com/","html_attributions":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `language` parameter affects the names of controls, copyright notices, driving directions, and control labels, as well as the responses to service requests. The effect on services is not as apparent.

For example, when geocoding street level addresses the country name is returned in the language you requested, but the rest of the address will be specific to the location you are geocoding. On the other hand, postal and political results are returned in the requested language.

Meaning you need to specify `region` bias as well. e.g. `?language=en-GB&region=GB`

Try this [demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demos/localization/) to experiment with the changes on the map when you update the language parameter.

More information [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization)

**Update:**

After looking into it, seems like it's a bug in autocomplete.

[image: Google Maps Autocomplete]

Comment: I have updated my code with the suggestions you made but still getting the same result.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, these parameters are the only way you can affect the language used. Check my answer for a screenshot.